# Tag info is completely wrong in app

Tags: bug, android-app, tag-score

The numbers in the app and the main site are not the same. (Both on MSO)

Main :

> [image]

App :

> [image]

Comment: It's not *wrong* exactly (the numbers are valid sums), it's just using completely inconsistent criteria to pick the numbers. Regardless, it should definitely be the same.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear as if the regular (browser-based) site is calculating the tag score based on answers-only, which is the expected behavior since that is what your tag score is for the purposes of tag badges.

However, a quick check of the Android app suggests that it is using all posts (questions and answers) to calculate.

Take the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) for example:

You have answered 8 questions in the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag, and the scores are:

```
7 + 6 + 2 + 0 + 5 + 2 + 11 + 1 = 34
```

which matches your [tag score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174490/insert-clever-xmas-name?tab=tags) on the main site

However, in the screen shot of the Android app, it is showing your tag score to be 136 in the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag.

If you consider your 15 questions asked before today (since today's questions won't be included until after the script runs tonight) in the bug tag as well:

```
2 + 4 + 4 + 10 + 13 + 0 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 6 + 5 + 47 + 3 + 0 + 3 = 102
```

And 34 + 102 = 136, which matches your screen shot.

The criteria for calculating the tag score between the app and the regular site is inconsistent, and I think it definitely needs to be adjusted.